# WP8 Development Hyper-v emulator fails because of virtual swtich/network configuration

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, hyper-v

I thought I'd try some Windows Phone development. I had to upgrade to Windows 8.1 Enterprise to do it so it's a fresh install.

When running the Windows Phone emulator from Visual Studio I get the following

> the emulator couldn't determine the host ip address, which is used to
>   communicate with the guest virtual machine

A few posts recommend removing the virtual switches and letting Visual Studio add them again as a fix.

When trying to remove switches from the Virtual Switch Manager in the Hyper-v manager I get the following

> the emulator couldn't determine the host ip address, which is used to
>   communicate with the guest virtual machine

Another post mentioned having to add yourself to a Hypervisor Administrator group but I can't find such a group and I'm already in Administrators and Hyper-v Administrators groups.

I've been through the WP8 Emulator troubleshooting guide on MSDN. I've tried uninstalling Hyper-v and re-installing it which does remove the switches but puts me back in the same situation when I run the emulator again.

I've no idea what to try now and I'm going round in circles reading forum posts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

usually a virtual switch just for the windows phone emulator is created. If for some reason it isn't working I'd suggest re-installing the Windows Phone SDK.